# redmineにてuninitialized constantエラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

使用しているRedmine (4.0.0) に以下のパッチを当てた後
http://www.redmine.org/issues/306#note-29

```
bundle
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

を実行しRedmineを再起動したところRedmine自体は動作するのですが、ファイル添付後目的の機能が動作しておらずログを見ると以下のログが出ておりました。

```
[ActiveJob] [ExtractFulltextJob] [3daafa4a-4d90-43ce-a065-c4257176ca0f] Error performing ExtractFulltextJob (Job ID: 3daafa4a-4d90-43ce-a065-c4257176ca0f) from Async(text_extraction) in 9.77ms: NameError (uninitialized constant Redmine::TextExtractor):
/home/redmine/redmine/app/jobs/extract_fulltext_job.rb:7:in `perform'
```

redmine/config/application.rbには以下の様に定義されており

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

redmine/lib/redmine/text_extractor.rb

```
module Redmine
  class TextExtractor
  ....
```

は存在しており、Classがないようにも見えないのですが、どこかで読み込み処理の様なものが必要なのでしょうか？

当方Rubyに対する見識がなく初歩的な事を聞いているとは思いますがよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/redmine)`を `application.rb`に追記すれば読み込みませんか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rails5においてはprocudtion環境においてはautoloadが走らないようです。
`config.enable_dependency_loading = true`
を追記することで解決しました